# Implicit flow, but requires access to multiple API's

Tags: identityserver3

Say I have a website secured with IdenityServer3. It uses the implicit flow so users are asked for their credentials. Now I'm facing a requirement where this application should access multiple (Web)API's on behalf of the user. These API's are secured using roles.

How do I go about this? Do I get one access_token for all by adding "token" to the ResponseType of the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions? Do I have to change the Implicit flow (to Hybrid?) and manually request access_tokens for each individual API and add those to the user's claims, after authentication?

I'm not sure on how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using Implicit flow and add "token" to reponse_type (so it becomes "id_token token"). That will give you access token as well. Additionally, you can specify any scopes that those APIs might require in order to include claims that might have to be present for API Authorize attribute to allow the call through.

Once you have the response from IdentityServer in your application along with access token, you call the api with that token in the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my requirement by moving to a Hybrid flow. For the response type I ended up needing "id_token", "token" and "code". I also had to retrieve the user claims manually in a separate request and manually add them to the user's identity, because adding "token" besides the "id_token" would remove all claims from the server response (to keep the token smaller).